# Fading slideshow not cycling through

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create a slideshow of images that fadew in and out, only my first image just keeps refreshing, Can anybody see where I may be going wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="active"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/400"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/350/500"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/370/600"/></a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow a IMG.active');

    if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('#slideshow a IMG:last');

    // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow a IMG:first');

    // uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order
    // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
    // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
    // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({
        opacity: 0.0
    }).addClass('active').animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
};

$(function() {
    setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eSrcr/1/

Comment: In future, please post your code ***here*** and rely on external sites only for demonstration purposes. In your case had JS Fiddle fallen over (again...) this question would have served no purpose, and be impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are using `next()` on your `$active` variable. There is no `next()` element because each `img` is contained in it's own `a`.

Try this instead:

```
var $next = $active.parent().next("a").find("img").length ? $active.parent().next("a").find("img") : $('#slideshow img:first');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eSrcr/4/)

You need to make sure you fade out/hide the previous image though, because they're all different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow a IMG:first');
```

with:

```
var $next =  $active.parent().next().find("img").length ? $active.parent().next().find("img")
    : $('#slideshow a IMG:first');
```